# How to concatenate two byte arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, concatenation

I am coding on the Arduino platform and I am trying to write something that will concatenate/append byte arrays in C.

```c
byte a[] = {a1, ..., an};
byte b[] = {b1, ..., bm};

byte c[] = a + b; // equivalent to {a1, ..., an, b1, ..., bm}
```

What is the best way to get the above result?

I tried searching online, however I have not had much luck. I saw another answer on SO highlighting the steps needed in order to do this however I could not follow them. They also say that there are libraries that deal with this kind of thing, however as I am on Arduino I am unsure whether or not these are totally available to me.

I understand there needs to be some sort of memory manipulation in order for this to work however I am new to these kinds of low level manipulations so they do not make too much sense to me. I have experience in higher languages (C#, Java and some C++).

---

I should also add: Can the same technique work for:

```
byte a[] = {a1, ..., an};
byte b[] = {b1, ..., bm};

a = a + b
```

Comment: Are the sizes fixed?

Comment: assuming `byte` is a `char` sized equivalent, `byte c[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b];` and two [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) calls would do it if that really is how `a` and `b` are declared.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. a and b are declared like this. However, I have edited the question to contain the case for when b is **appended** to a as well.

Comment: @Alizter that isn't going to happen unless `a` is initially sized to accommodate its data and space for appended data And a `memcpy`-type operation is still involved sooner or later. Regardless, the syntax you're using is definitely not congruent with the C language.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I am aware that it is definitely not C. I have written it in a pseudo style to better explain my trouble.

Comment: @Alizter more complex cases, i.e. where you get the size at runtime would require `malloc()` for the first case, and `realloc()` in the second case, but all of them would use `memcpy()` to copy the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `byte` type in C. Unless it's some type definition, you could use `unsigned char` or some fixed type from `<stdint.h>` portably. Anyway, here is some solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char a[3+3] = {1, 2, 3}; // n+m
    unsigned char b[3]   = {4, 5, 6}; // m

    memcpy(a+3, b, 3); // a+n is destination, b is source and third argument is m

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure that array `a` has room for at least `n + m` elements (here `n = 3` and `m = 3` as well) in order to avoid issues with array overflow (i.e. undefined behavior, that may crash yor program or even worse).

Comment: How would you make sure that a has enough room?

Comment: @Alizter  `unsigned char a[3 + 3]` has room for the initial `a` + the appended `b` obviously.

Comment: @iharob Oh! I though there was some size I was missing. Of course.

Comment: So if we were to talk about an array `c`, assuming `a` and `b` are full, we would need to make `c` the 'length' of a + b and then copy using `memcpy()` into c `b` then `a`. What I am unsure of though is the `a+3` syntax you have used. What does that mean?

Comment: @Alizter: Oh, my cognition only registered `a=a+b` case. In order of `c=a+b` you need to copy `a` to `c`, then `b` to `c+n`. The `c+n` works in the same way as `a+3`. The `a` "decays" (or more formaly is converted) to address of first element in array. By `+` operator with integer you are performing pointer arithmetic. The `a+3` is equivalent to `&a[3]` so I believe you get an idea now.

Answer (score 0):

If the sizes are known you can simply create a new byte array of that size and use simple loops to fill it.

Comment: No, no loops need to be involved.